# Get rows from DataFrame based on array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have an array with numbers which corresponds to the row numbers that need to be selected from a DataFrame. 
For example, `arr = np.array([0,0,1,1])` and the DataFrame is seen below. `arr` is the row number and not the index.

```
Index   A   B   C   D
3      10   0   0   0
4      5    2   0   0
```

Using `arr` I would like to produce a DataFrame that looks like this

```
  Index    A    B   C   D
    3      10   0   0   0
    3      10   0   0   0
    4      5    2   0   0
    4      5    2   0   0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `iloc` with integer indexing:

```
df.iloc[[0,0,1,1], :]   # or df.iloc[arr, :]

#    A  B   C   D
#Index              
#3  10  0   0   0
#3  10  0   0   0
#4   5  2   0   0
#4   5  2   0   0
```

Comment: Nice. I think `df.iloc[arr]` also works in this case.